# How to add an attachment to Google calendar from Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm using intent to create a new event in google calendar application.

However i don't find a way to add a photo as an attachment.

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
                    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                    intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Learn Android");
                    intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Home sweet home");
                    intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, mImageUri);


intent.putExtra(Events.A, mImageUri); ===> ?
```

How do i do this?

Comment: Have you got any solution about this attachment option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it unfortunately isn't supported by API but I could be wrong. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#events) is full event table and there is nothing about attachments.

**EDIT :**

This feature is still a lab, and Google for now won't expose it via the API. See the [source](http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2545).